# In MS Access is there a way to allow forms to update while maintaning Read Only

Tags: ms-access

I have several forms linked tables via queries. The form pull data such as sales and ratios by selecting a product from the main's form's combo box.

I am however having to issues:

1- I would ultimately prefer the combo box to be a free entry; however by just entering in the box and hitting enter (not a button called “enter on a screen” which would initiate recalcs, just normal enter), while it does bring the new information in sub-forms it also changes the information in the original table. If I make the table read only that it just doesn't allow the form to work by saying that the table is read only.

2- The same Read only issue occurs when another user with read only rights tries to use the database.

I understand that ready only is functioning as intended, however I am wondering if there is way to make some functions work while disallowing the updating. 

I am unfortunately learning on the go, so go easy plz. 

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your combo box no linked to the underlying data, but once the data is changed, set/reset the value of the combo box.  This way, if some types in a new value
A) it will not update the data whether it is updatable or not.

B) you can still have the subforms update based on this value

```
Private Sub Form_Current()
    cmbMyDisplayOnlyComboBox = Me!WhatEverFieldHasTheValue
End Sub
```

Again, cmbMyDisplayOnlyComboBox Control Source is blank. Substitute the field that 'use' to be the Control Source as WhatEverFieldHasTheValue